# How am I able to tell whether it is dark or not while eyes closed?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, vision

How am I able to tell whether there is a light on in front of me even with my eyes closed?

The usual darkness whilst eyes closed transforms into a not so bright glow when my closed eyes are in front of a light source? How am I able to intercept light when my eyes are closed?

Comment: Your eyelids are transparent to some frequencies. Your hand too. Enclose a flashlight in your fist at night and you will see the light through your hand. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency It is actually called translucency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eye lids aren't 100% opaque. It's translucent, so your retina is able to receive few photons.

Answer (score 2):

Flesh is sort of like a blob of goo infused with blood, so it tends to transmit certain wavelengths (like red) somewhat effectively. This is called the [optical window of tissue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_window_in_biological_tissue). Transmission pulse oximetry, among other things, takes advantage of this partial transmissivity.